# How to parse div> main>div

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

[Image of the source code I want to parse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln6bk.png)

How to parse  `div class="flight-selector-listing"`?

How to open `"main[ui-view]"` and going next

But I only have

`Element masthead = doc.select("div.FR>main[ui-view]").first();`

and Output:
`<main ui-view="mainView"></main>`

Comment: Hi, Denis. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll need to make your question more clear for us. Can you try and rephrase it?

Comment: You may wish to edit your question after reading [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). e.g. posting code as an image is frowned upon.

Comment: Can you please add the url of the page you're working on?

Comment: https://www.ryanair.com/gb/en/booking/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to parse  div class="flight-selector-listing"?

Use this CSS query:

```
div.flight-selector-listing
```

> How to open "main[ui-view]" and going next

Jsoup is an HTML parser. He won't be able to "open" anything. If you want to open `"main[ui-view]"` then use tools like [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j).

> (...) and Output:

I bet `div.FR>main[ui-view]` is populated by some Javascript code running on the page. If it is the case, Jsoup can't help here.